# Using fold expressions to print all variadic arguments with newlines inbetween

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++17, fold-expression

The classic example for C++17 fold expressions is printing all arguments:

```
template<typename ... Args>
void print(Args ... args)
{
    (cout << ... << args);
}
```

Example:

```
print("Hello", 12, 234.3, complex<float>{12.3f, 32.8f});
```

Output:

```
Hello12234.3(12.3,32.8)
```

I'd like to add newlines to my output. However, I can't find a good way to do that, the best I've found so far:

```
template<typename ... Args>
void print(Args ... args)
{
    (cout << ... << ((std::ostringstream{} << args << "\n").str()));
}
```

This however isn't zero-overhead, as it constructs a temporary `ostringstream` for each argument.

The following versions don't work either:

```
(cout << ... << " " << args);

error: expression not permitted as operand of fold expression
```

And

```
(cout << ... << (" " << args));

error: invalid operands to binary expression
```

I understand why the last two versions don't work.
Is there a more elegant solution to this problem, using fold expressions?

Comment: Two good answers so far, thanks! Seems there is no 'elegant' way to do this, then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`repeat` takes a function object `f`, and return a new function object.  The return value runs f on each of its args.  It "repeats" `f` on each of its args.

```
template<class F>
auto repeat( F&& f ) {
  return [f=std::forward<F>(f)](auto&&...args)mutable{
    ( void(f(args)), ... );
  };
}
```

Use:

```
repeat
( [](auto&&x){ std::cout << x << "\n"; } )
( args... );
```

This uses fold expressions, but only indirectly.  And honestly, you could have written this in C++14 (just the body of `repeat` would be uglier).

We could also write a streamer that works with `<<` to do it "more inline" and use fold expressions directly:

```
template<class F>
struct ostreamer_t {
  F f;
  friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, ostreamer_t&& self ) {
    std::move(self).f(os);
    return os;
  }
};

template<class F>
ostreamer_t<F> ostreamer( F&& f ) { return {std::forward<F>(f)}; }
```

then we use it like this:

```
(std::cout << ... << ostreamer([&](auto&& os){ os << " " << args;}));
```

`ostreamer` takes a function object.  It returns an object that overloads `<<` such that when you pass it an ostream on the left, it invokes the function object with the ostream.

No temporary stream is created.

[Live examples](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb51d6ddf8178a05).

Comment: Ah, nice trick, I didn't think of overloading the operator<<. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Update: [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c)'s comment below provided a better solution:

```
template<typename ... Args>
void print(Args ... args)
{
    ((cout << args << '\n'), ...);
}
```

---

You can use a *fold expression* over the *comma operator*:

```
template<typename ... Args>
void print(Args ... args)
{
    ([](const auto& x){ cout << x << "\n"; }(args), ...);
}
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    print("a", 1, 1000);
}
```

> a
>
> 1
>
> 1000

*(Note: this prints a trailing newline as well.)*

- [**live wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6cbnRiTyphIaf2yh)
- [**assembly comparison on godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/g/KbEkpi)

---

Explanation:

- `[](const auto& x){ cout << x << "\n"; }` is a lambda that given `x` prints `x` and `'\n'`.
- `[](const auto& x){ cout << x << "\n"; }(args)` immediately invokes the lambda with `args`.
- `([](const auto& x){ cout << x << "\n"; }(args), ...)` is a fold expression over the *comma operator* that expands in the following way:

  ```
  // (pseudocode)
  [](const auto& x){ cout << x << "\n"; }(args<0>),
  [](const auto& x){ cout << x << "\n"; }(args<1>),
  [](const auto& x){ cout << x << "\n"; }(args<2>),
  // ...
  [](const auto& x){ cout << x << "\n"; }(args<N>)
  ```

Comment: Why lambda? `((cout << args << '\n'), ...)`

Comment: @T.C. ah, nice - this is even simpler than I expected. I used a lambda because my thought process was *"converting `for_each_argument(f, args...)` into a fold expression over the comma operator"*, but that was highly unnecessary.

Comment: Interesting solution, thanks! Why is this only possible in C++17, I thought C++11 also allows expanding over a comma? But why is this specific case not possible in C++11?

Comment: This is a *fold expression* over the comma operator. C++11 allows a similar technique (`for_each_argument`) by (ab)using contexts where an expansion can take place. [I gave a talk about that at CppCon 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2l83JlqkzBk) that explains how it works.

Comment: Is there a way to print without trailing newline?