# C++ Function with variable number and types of arguments as argument of another function

Tags: c++, function, bind

I would like to create function calling another function and printing its arguments.
It should be compatible with many functions (returning the same result) with many combinations of variables of arguments.

I would like to have something like this:

```cpp
int fun1(){}
int fun2(int i){}
int fun3(std::string s, int i){}

void execute_and_print(std::function f, ...)
{
///code
}

int main()
{
execute_and_print(&fun1);
execute_and_print(&fun2, 3);
execute_and_print(&fun3,"ff",4);
}
```

It could print:

```
executed function with arguments:
executed function with arguments: 3
executed function with arguments: ff, 4
```

Is it even possible in C++?

Comment: Look up "call forwarding" in C++ tag, you'll find multiple solutions. The key is to make `execute_and_print` a variadic template. This way it would be able to call any function that you pass it. It wouldn't be of type `std::function`, though.

Comment: There's no point in converting it to std::function because it's going to be templated anyway.

Comment: See [c++ - Using fold expressions to print all variadic arguments with newlines inbetween - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070062/using-fold-expressions-to-print-all-variadic-arguments-with-newlines-inbetween) for the printing part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not foolproof, but any possible errors will be caught at compile time (ie. the code will not compile). It should work file, as long as the provided parameters match those of the called function, and a matching `<<` operator exists for each parameter.

```
template<class Fn, class...Args>
void execute_and_print(Fn fn, Args...args) {
    int f[sizeof...(Args)] = { (std::cout << args << ", ", 0)... };
    fn(args...);
}
```

Refer to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack. The `sizeof...` command is actually the number of elements, not their combined size.

Comment: I doubt this thing really works in C++... `i` isn't even constexpr.

Comment: Yes, sorry for misleading and thanks for pointing that out. Willl edit that in the answer.

Comment: There might be an issue if there isn't any arguments, the array size will be 0 (the IDE and the compiler will complain).

Answer (score 5):

In C++17 it is very simple

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
void execute_and_print(F f, Args... args)
{
    (std::cout << ... << args);
    f(args...);
}
```

Prior to that there is extra ceremony

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
void execute_and_print(F f, Args... args)
{
    int dummy[] = { (static_cast<void>(std::cout << args), 0)... };
    f(args...);
}
```

Comment: First and the second examples didn't work in MSVC C++17 and C++14.

Comment: First example: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<<’ token  
     std::cout << ... << args;
Second one: error: too many decimal points in number  
     int dummy[] = { static_cast<void>(std::cout << args), 0... };

Comment: @pktiuk: typos should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use templates to get it done,

```cpp
template <class... Args>
void RunThrough(Args&& ... args)
{
    ([&](auto& input)
        {
            std::cout << input << ", ";
        } (args), ...);
}

template<class Func, class... Args>
decltype(auto) execute_and_print(Func f, Args&&... args)
{
    f(args...);

    std::cout << "executed function with arguments: ";
    RunThrough(args...);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

You can use lambdas, `std::function` objects and function pointers in this.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60136761/11228029