# print a list using variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, variadic-templates

I need your help to find out why does following code not compile.

```
#include <iostream>

template <int I>
void foo(){
  std::cout << I << std::endl;
  std::cout << "end of list" << std::endl;
}

template <int I, int ... Ints>
void foo(){
  std::cout << I << std::endl;
  foo<Ints...>();
}


int main(){
  foo<1, 2>();
  return 0;
}
```

I am getting this error.

```
function_parameter_pack.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void foo() [with int I = 1; int ...Ints = {2}]’:
function_parameter_pack.cpp:17:13:   required from here
function_parameter_pack.cpp:12:15: error: call of overloaded ‘foo<2>()’ is ambiguous
   foo<Ints...>();
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
function_parameter_pack.cpp:4:6: note: candidate: void foo() [with int I = 2]
 void foo(){
      ^~~
function_parameter_pack.cpp:10:6: note: candidate: void foo() [with int I = 2; int ...Ints = {}]
 void foo(){
```

Isn't a more specialized function is supposed to be chosen? i.e one with only one template(the first one).

Comment: "More specialized" is done though parameters, not template parameter; as for empty pack  tie-break.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Best_viable_function and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading

Comment: For a C++17 solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43070233

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foo<2>` matches both templates equally well (since `int...` matches zero `int`s too) which is why the compiler complains about ambiguity.

> Isn't a more specialized function is supposed to be chosen?

Yes, but a these are equally special. Deducing which is the more specialized matching function is done by looking at the arguments to the function, not the template parameters.

One way to solve that is to make the second function template take 2 or more template parameters:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int I>
void foo() {
    std::cout << I << std::endl;
    std::cout << "end of list" << std::endl;
}

template<int I, int J, int... Ints>
void foo() {
    std::cout << I << std::endl;
    foo<J, Ints...>();
}

int main() {
    foo<1>();
    foo<1, 2>();
    foo<1, 2, 3>();
}
```

Comment: Note that reason is (over-)simplified though, as `template <typename T> void f(T); template <typename T, typename ...Ts> void f(T, Ts...);` and `f(42);` would compile, even if `f<int>` matches both template.

Comment: @Jarod42 True. I know that part too bad to express why that is. Something about the non-type template parameters in the question I guess? I'll happily upvote if you put up an answer to explain it. :-)

Comment: Overload resolution has plenty of rules, and as my first comment, *""More specialized" is done though parameters, not template parameter"*. So, unrelated to type/non type template parameters.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah, I didn't notice that comment. Thanks. I put that in the answer and I tried using my own words. I hope I didn't mess it up.

Comment: @Jarod42 Could you please explain why would the code you wrote in comment compile but not the one asked in question. Isn't is the same? Am I missing something?

Comment: My functions use **parameters/arguments** (in addition to template parameters).

Answer (score 3):

Another way to solve the problem is using a do-nothing terminal recursion function accepting something different from a value (maybe a typename), but with a default,

```
template <typename = void>
void foo() {
  std::cout << "end of list" << std::endl;
}
```

that intercept a `foo<Ints...>()` call when `Ints...` is empty.

The recursive case, that intercept every template integer value, remain the same

```
template <int I, int ... Ints>
void foo(){
  std::cout << I << std::endl;
  foo<Ints...>();
}
```

Comment: Another way is to get rid of recursion: `template <int ... Is>
void foo() { for (int i : {Is...}) {std::cout << i << std::endl;} std::cout << "end of list\n";}` :-) (or C++17 fold expression `((std::cout << Is << std::endl), ...);` (or equivalent trick for C++11)).

Comment: @Jarod42 - I know... and is better avoid recursion... but I interpret the question more about the recursion management than the execution of the body of the functions.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer solution which uses dummy array, so it works similarly to fold expression.

```cpp
template<int... Ints>
void foo() {
    char dummy[] {((std::cout << Ints << ','), '0')...};
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1Y1noK

Comment: Regular for range does the trick here `for (int i : {Is...})` :-)

Comment: Why not just the fold expression? It has the same sequencing guarantees.

Comment: Fold expressions are in C++17 and question is tagged with C++11

Comment: Sorry, did not notice that.